# Is there any alternative of node_save to update database fields in iteration?

Tags: 7, nodes

In Drupal 7, we have big product catalog where we need to update price and stock frequently via Cronjobs.

If we update only 5000 prices then also it takes around 20 min.
In each iteration we use `node_load()` and `node_save()` functions to update for each product in database.

It seems that these functions are consuming more memory and taking more execution time to just update 1/2 fields in database.
It's drupal's API, so it would be integrated to some other stuff (like node revision) so I doubt that we can simply replace node functions with direct queries.

But I think, this scenario would be common when we manage large product catalog in drupal.

Can anyone suggest better/optimized approach for this scenario where it doesn't break the integrity with drupal platform?

Comment: `field_attach_update()` is the usual approach - it'll cut some of the crap out, but it will still write values for every field. The API doesn't have anything with half-measures, so performing manual queries/cache clearing etc is really your only other option

Comment: drupal_write_record($table, &$record, $primary_keys = array()) Saves (inserts or updates) a record to the database based upon the schema.

Comment: are you sure this approach won't break any integrity with basic Drupal functionality like I saw that with `node_save()` function, it updates node revision?

Comment: With my limited knowledge of SQL, I think the approach would be to write one long SQL string of `UPDATE`s and execute it only once. I think you'll gain biggest performance as your calls to the database (at least 5000 times previously) will be just 1 time. But you'll miss out on all the things that `node_save` does (such as update the updated date, call hooks & alters, write new revisions etc).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module. This module proves [entity_matadata_wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) API which allows you to load and save fields of nodes. The following code is an example of altering a node's title.

```
$nodeWrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', node_load($node->nid));
$nodeWrapper->title->set(t("Saved by Entity Save"));
$nodeWrapper->save();
```

`entity_matadata_wrapper` is not limited to nodes. As you can see in it's signature you must specify the element which in your case it is node.

Comment: and alisha20,
Thanks both of you. I'll check with benchmarking that which approach gives better performance.
do any of the solution handles with prepared statements for SQL queries internally? or can we do it somehow with these approaches? because I believe prepared statements can also improve performance.

Comment: @KulinChoksi I don't think so, at least in case of my solution. But writing  in database is much more time consuming than reading from database. `entity_metadata_wrapper` saves the node only by saving the selected fields. So I guess it deserves more attention.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. `entity_metadata_wrapper` saves the node for selected fields but internally it writes something in database. and that's why I'm thinking of using prepared statements. or I misunderstood something?